# how to generate multipile random number sequences independently in c++?

Tags: c++

in my view, a seeded pseudo-random number generator will produce a deterministic sequence of numbers. in order to get 2 random sequence in one program, 2 generators with different seed are needed. that is:

```
default_random_engine gen1(1);
default_random_engine gen1(2);
uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 5);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    seq1[i] = dist(gen1);
    seq2[i] = dist(gen2);
}
```

1. can i use only 1 generator to produce 2 independant sequences?
2. should i create a new distribution object for each sequence?

Comment: Maybe you could ask here instead: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It might be worth indicating if this is out of curiosity or if you have a real requirement here.  Usually a pseudo randum number is sufficient and you use them or they are not and you avoid them completely.  Wanting independent streams of psudo random numbers is unlike to be a real solution to any problem.

Comment: "_in my view, a seeded pseudo-random number generator will produce a deterministic sequence of numbers._" - your view is wrong. (Deterministic is not the opposite of truly random. There is an unhappy medium.) If you're on a Linux-based system just read bytes from `/dev/urandom`

Comment: @roaima You are mistaken.  The C++ random number generators do NOT take in additional entropy after seeding.  It is less a view and more a simple fact that C++ random functions will return the same sequence of random numbers for the same seed. The statement that they are deterministic is plainly correct  See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can i use only 1 generator to produce 2 independent sequences?

Well, yes and no.

If the sequence from a single generator were "truly" a sequence of independent and identically distributed samples (quotes since the meaning of that term is actually problematic) - then you can take the odd elements and the even elements in the sequence of generated values and have your two independent sequences.

Now, the PRNG is, as the same suggests, only pseudo-random. That doesn't mean it *isn't* "random" - the language standard doesn't require it to be deterministic. Also, it could be using some thermal noise, which may not be random but may be indistinguishable from it by you. But it could also be perfectly deterministic, in which case, given a short part of the odd sequence, it is theoretically possible to determine the even sequence.

For most purposes which do not have strong requirements about the source distribution, and in practice, you can treat the odd-element and even-element sequences as independent and identically distributed.

> Should I create a new distribution object for each sequence?

Probably. The C++ distribution class is a misnomer; it is a "sampler" class, with an underlying sample space characterized by a certain distribution; and where `operator()` performs the sampling. So don't think of it as "a different distribution" - same distribution, another sample space.

Answer (score 0):

> can i use only 1 generator to produce 2 independant sequences?

Most likely no.

> should i create a new distribution object for each sequence?

Yes. A distribution may or may not have additional hidden state that affects the results.